# C++: Static vector defined in base class loses it's value in main

Tags: class, c++11, inheritance, vector, static

I defined a static vector (to be used as a default argument to one of the member function) in base class (Base1). When I inherit this class along with Base2 class in the Derived class, the value of the static vector is fine in the derived class constructor. However it is lost inside main() function.

**base2.hh**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

class Base2 {
 public:
  Base2() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
      AllPorts.push_back(i);
    }
  };

  static vector<uint32_t> AllPorts;

  void Reset(vector<uint32_t> ports = AllPorts);
};
```

**base2.cc**

```
#include "base2.hh"

vector<uint32_t> Base2::AllPorts;

void Base2::Reset(vector<uint32_t> ports) {
  cout << "Base2::Reset AllPorts.size = " << Base2::AllPorts.size() << endl;
}
```

**base1.hh**

```
class Base1 {
 public:
  friend class Temp;

  Base1() {
    ptr_ = this;
  };

  virtual int Main(int argc, char **argv) = 0;
 private:
  static class Base1 *ptr_;
};

class Temp {
 public:
  int Run (int argc, char **argv) {
    return Base1::ptr_->Main(argc, argv);
  };

  Temp() {};
};

#define REGISTER_PROC(name) name __##name
```

**base1.cc**

```
#include "base1.hh"

class Base1 *Base1::ptr_ = nullptr;

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
  class Temp obj;

  return obj.Run(argc, argv);
}
```

**derived.hh**

```
#include "base1.hh"
#include "base2.hh"

class Derived final : public Base1, public Base2 {
 public:
  Derived() : Base1(), Base2() {
    cout << "Derived::Derived AllPorts.size = " << Base2::AllPorts.size() << endl;
  };

  int Main (int argc, char** argv) {
    cout << "Derived::Main AllPorts.size = " << Base2::AllPorts.size() << endl;
    Reset();
    return 0;
  };
};
```

**derived.cc**

```
#include "derived.hh"

REGISTER_PROC(Derived);
```

**Console output when the exe is run:**

```
$ ./daemon
Derived::Derived AllPorts.size = 32
Derived::Main AllPorts.size = 0
Base2::Reset AllPorts.size = 0
```

Any ideas on what could be going wrong? Thanks in advance.

Additional info:
'daemon' executable is created from derived.cc and this exe is linked to 2 libraries - one created from base1.cc and other from base2.cc. Note that main is defined in base2.cc.

**BUILD file**

```
cc_library (
    name = "base1",
    srcs = ["base1.cc"],
    hdrs = ["base1.hh"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)

cc_library (
    name = "base2",
    srcs = ["base2.cc"],
    hdrs = ["base2.hh"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)

cc_binary(
    name = "daemon",
    srcs = ["derived.cc", "derived.hh",],
    deps = ["base1", "base2",],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

Also, noted that if the static variable is of built-in data-type, the value is not lost in main(). Tried with int and std::string, value is not lost when static variable is of type int, while it's lost with type std::string.

EDIT1:
1. Replaced pseudo code with running and verified code. 
2. Removed gdb output and added console output after exe is run.
3. Added BUILD file.

Comment: Your gdb session refers to `Base1::AllPorts`, but your code shows `Base2::AllPorts`. Also, the debugging session suggests the existence of output statements absent from the code shown. It's best if you prepare a [mcve].

Comment: If `obj` is a a global variable in a separate source file than the definition of `AllPorts` then it's probably a case of the static initialization order fiasco (i.e. `AllPorts` get constructed **after** `obj`. (you just got lucky with UB that it didn't crash then and there)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: Added verified code and reproduced the issue (evident from console logs).

Comment: @Frank: That's a valid point, but it doesn't seem that is the case here. If you see the console output, the constructor Derived::Derived (which will be called when object of class Derived is declared) prints the size of AllPorts correctly.

Comment: @Piyush it prints the size it interprets from the uninitialized memory (probably zeros).

Comment: "static variable is of built-in data-type, the value is not lost in main()." Well yeah, those values are set at compilation, not constructed at runtime.

Comment: Ah. You originally claimed that an instance of `Derived` is constructed as a local variable in `main`, but in your actual code it's a global variable. So what happens is this: 1) the memory for `AllPorts` is set to all-zeros at program startup, and that just happens to look like a valid empty vector; 2) `Derived` constructor runs, and populates `AllPorts` (or rather, memory where `AllPorts` will eventually be created); 3) `AllPorts` constructor runs, initializing it to an empty vector, and in the process leaking previously "inserted" data.

Comment: You have two global variables, defined in different translation units. The order of initialization is unspecified, and it so happens that `__Derived` gets constructed before `AllPorts`. Its constructor then accesses an object before its lifetime has started, whereupon your program exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thanks! Makes sense. But I wonder how `Base1::ptr_` always retains it's value given that it is also static. Is there a way to order the initialization such that the issue is avoided?

Comment: `Base1::ptr_` doesn't have step 3 - it doesn't have a constructor to dynamically run. It's initialized to `nullptr` essentially as a side effect of loading the executable image into memory.

Comment: Got it. I tried this for AllPorts definition - `vector<uint32_t> Base2::AllPorts(AllPorts.begin(), AllPorts.end());`. This seems to resolve the issue. Looks like AllPorts.begin() and AllPorts.end() still point to the memory allocated in step 2.